# Decode json array

Tags: java, php, json

I have this json string and want to decode it and use it. But below the print result is empty.

```
$data = '{"Category":
06-30 16:23:52.198: I/s(23262): [{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":1,"name":"علی"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":2,"name":"گ"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":3,"name":"علی"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":4,"name":"ولی"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":5,"name":"ن"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":6,"name":"تتاا"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":7,"name":"بی اسم"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":8,"name":"تسلام"},{"class":"ir.aiga.apps.datastore.db.CategoryModel","id":9,"name":"میدانم"}]}';

print json_decode($data)->{'Category'};
```

I use below code in java to produce the json string

```
String s = "{\"Category\":\n";

List<CategoryModel> pmo = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
        pmo = CategoryModule.getAllRecords(c);
        s += new JSONSerializer().serialize(pmo);
s += "\n}";
```

what's problem ?

Comment: Wrong syntax. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: this syntax in result of jsonSerialize() class in java. I did not any change in string.

Comment: Are there really random numbers (looks like part of a timestamp) in the middle of your string? If so, that's quite obviously your problem.

Comment: @ali: No, no JSON serializer produced that. Maybe some logging tool mangled it when outputting it, but no JSON serializer did.

Comment: I use this code to produce the json string . String s = "{\"Category\":\n";
 
  List<CategoryModel> pmo = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
  pmo = CategoryModule.getAllRecord s(c);
  s += new JSONSerializer().serialize(pmo);  s += "\n}";

Comment: I updated question, refresh @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ali: **As I said,** No JSON serializer produced that. Maybe some logging tool mangled it when outputting it, but no JSON serializer did. It looks like you copied this from a log file and didn't bother to notice that there were timestamps in the file.

Comment: Yes i copied it from LogCat thank you

Comment: So...remove the parts that aren't relevant. The JSON's fine if you remove the rubbish from the middle of it.

Comment: I want to access id=2, how should it do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categories =  json_decode($data)->{'Category'};
foreach($categories as $category){
   echo $category-{'id'};
}
```